# variable not interpolating for Mysql query with flask

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask

I have the following code where the `ph` variable does not interpolates with the select query.

I am just trying to access http://localhost/testing?phone_number=1234567890 it returns like `()` rather particular record of the phone number.

```
@app.route("/testing",methods=['GET')
def testing():
  ph = request.args.get('phone_number')
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM client_base where phone_number={}'''.format(ph))
  results = cur.fetchall()
  return ''' {} '''.format(results)
```

Comment: phonenumber as firstname? really

Comment: @nbk correct.. i have changed it. still not works.

Answer (score 0):

Abetter solution is using prepared statements like below

```
@app.route("/testing",methods=['GET')
def testing():
  ph = request.args.get('phone_number')
  cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
  cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM client_base where phone_number=%s''',(ph,))
  results = cur.fetchall()
  return ''' {} '''.format(results)
```